# Protractor: Finding Element by Div Text

Tags: html, protractor

Hey I have this code in one of my div elements:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">Account Information: </div>
```

Can someone tell me how I would go about finding this element in my protractor code? Is it possible to do something like this:

expect(element(by.divText('Account Information: ')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

I have multiple elements with the class "col-sm-8" so I am not able to find the element by class. I was just wondering if there is any way to possibly find the element using the text in the div element? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [by.cssContainingText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText)

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.col-sm-8', 'Account Information'))
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer I found on SO, thanks 

Comment: how would you differentiate between items in the case where one was 'Account Information', another was 'Information' and a third was 'Account'?

Comment: You just change the string in the second argument of `cssContainingText` `element(by.cssContainingText('.col-sm-8', 'Account Information'))`. If you wanted to check for "Information" it would be `element(by.cssContainingText('.col-sm-8', 'Information'))`

Answer (score 7):

There is no webdriver method which would allow locating an element by its text. You could try using xpath in the following way (not tested):

```
element(by.xpath('//div[contains(text(), "Account Information: ")]')
```

Comment: yep, you can see that the xpath locator is more human readable than the cssContainingText locator.

Answer (score 3):

keep in mind `by.cssContainingText` matches the element by PARTIAL text

so `element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'male'))` will actually match both `male` and `female` text

To solve this, use xpath with exact text match

```
element(by.xpath('//div[text()="male"]'))
```