# Protractor - locate element by both className and text

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a situation in my web application where some listed items do share common className that is used by our automated test suites. Now, I have to click on specific element and need to locate it by it's class and text of that element.

Here is an example:

```
<ul>
   <li class="autotest-list">Milk</li>
   <li class="autotest-list">Sugar</li>
   <li class="autotest-list">Candy</li>
</ul>
```

I need a way how to click on ie.Sugar.
Something like this:

```
element(by.className('autotest-list').text('Sugar');
```

or this

```
element(by.className('autotest-list')&&text('Sugar');
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016080/protractor-finding-element-by-div-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind, you could use `by.xpath`:

```
element(by.xpath('li[@class="auto test-list" and text()="Sugar"]'))
```

Comment: not necessary to use xpath, protractor has a method `cssContainingText` for finding elements by their text

Comment: cssContainingText is working good but it also has a limitation, because of "Containing" part. In this example:
<ul>
   <li class="autotest-list">Sugar Stick</li>   
   <li class="autotest-list">Milk</li>
   <li class="autotest-list">Sugar</li>
</ul>
it will locate the 1st element Containing the word Sugar, which here is "Sugar Stick" and that was not an intention.

Thank you anyway mr.@Gunderson

Comment: @Alen so you are using xpath now?

Answer (score 2):

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.autotest-list','Sugar')
```